# Поблема c json_encode в PHP при приёме заголовков от C++ клиента (кодировки)

Tags: php, c++, кодировка, header

Серверный скрипт PHP принимает запросы от клиентов на C++... В заголовке идёт параметр `Name: имя_пользователя`, который при `json_encode` становится `null`. Если смотреть в notepad++ exe-файл клиента, то он в кодировке windows-1251 (параметры дописаны в конец клиента и он себя читает для инициализации переменных). Естественно `json_encode` требует utf-8. Попытки преобразовать в utf-8 на стороне сервера посредством `utf8_encode` или `mb_convert_encoding` дали на выходе что-то непонятное, а не русский текст (хоть не `null` уже). `mb_detect_encoding` при приёме данного параметра возвращает `UTF-8` хотя `json_encode` всё равно пишет `null`

**Как выйти из данной ситуации?** Можно ли решить проблему на php или обязательно надо в клиенте писать функцию типа `string_cp1251_to_string_utf8` для одной единственной переменной?

Comment: На php не делал детект кодировки (на c# делал). Поступите так, раз вернулось null, то пробуйте к запросу применить 1251 кодировку. Либо анализируйте массив байтов запроса, на наличие характерных для UTF-8 комбинаций - большого колличества байт D0 D1 C0 C1 например

Comment: Не совсем понятно? c++ клиент отправляет какой-то файл? Какого формата файл? Как он передается в json_encode()?

Comment: Клиент отправляет не файл, а POST-запрос с заголовками на HTTP-сервер. Один из заголовков - Name: имя_клиента. Сервер парсит заколовки, и дедает json_encode(array($Headers['ID']=>$Headers['Name']));. Вот этот Name выходит Null после json_encode, а должна быть закодированная эксейп-последовательностью строка с кириллицей, которая при echo json_decode должна давать читаемое имя пользователя

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php

Comment: @E_p, а если mb_detect_encoding на сервере возвращает UTF-8, когда из клиента выходит по факту cp1251, приведёт ли iconv строку к реальной UTF-8, которую примет json_encode?

Comment: @Iceman Не уверен, тут надо пробовать :).

Comment: @E_p, просто, как я уже писал выше, пробовал использовать utf8_encode и mb_convert_encoding - на выходе уже был не null, но и не русский текст... какие-то иероглифы